# Need MongoDB Query

Tags: mongodb

I'm sorry but I'm little confuse with a query , Kindly help. suppose we've one document that contains

```
{  
   "_id":100,
   "name":"Demarcus Audette",
   "scores":[  
      {  
         "score":47.42608580155614,
         "type":"exam"
      },
      {  
         "score":44.83416623719906,
         "type":"quiz"
      },
      {  
         "score":39.01726616178844,
         "type":"homework"
      },
         "score":89.01726616178844,
         "type":"homework"
      }
   ]
}
```

And I want to write a query that should return only rows which contains homework in that , that means the out put should be like below

```
{  
   "_id":100,
   "name":"Demarcus Audette",
   "scores":[  
      {  
         "score":39.01726616178844,
         "type":"homework"
      },
         "score":89.01726616178844,
         "type":"homework"
      }
   ]
}
```

Kindly suggest. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Rows that contain homework? By the way, is that your homework assignment for today?

Comment: @joao I really don't see any other solution to this other than for someone from MongoDB to monitor these questions and issue a "take down" request to SO corporate as they are found. This is clearly going to happen in bulk every time the open course is run. The off-book moderators have made it clear they will not remove the questions themselves. If these are heavily downvoted then they can be deleted. But the existing close reasons are too open to other moderators to reverse with a re-open.

Comment: Yes , it is part of my homework but I'm trying to filter it out in order to get the ans but I'm not getting how to write query for the above question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/#elemmatch-projection) operator.

```
db.collection.find({ "scores": { $elemMatch: { "type": "homework" } } } );
```

**EDIT**

What you are asking is not possible. You will need the above query and filter out the rest in whatever language you are programming. You can also use an aggregate function using [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/).

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    {$unwind: "$messages"},
    {$match: {"scores.type": "homework"}}
);
```

[`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) flattens your array and [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) is your actually query which will return matching documents. *Please note* that $unwind will create a different document for each element in your array. This means you will get two results when you filter on 'homework' according to your example.

Comment: Hi, I tried the query as mentioned above but doesn't look like it is working as expected , it is returning all the records that is present there in the document. Kindly suggest me any other alternative for this.

Comment: @user2513120 I have edited my answer but (according to me) the result you want to achieve, is not possible in MongoDB alone.

Comment: Thank you so much for your expert advice . But I'm wondering what is the technical reason behind that , if you can explain me a little bit that would be great and much appropriated.

Comment: @user2513120 Why it is not possible or how the above queries work? Because I cannot answer the first question, there is just no MongoDB selector to my knowledge.